# var self = this in Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am dealing with some scope issues while using Coffeescript.

```
drawFirstLine: (currentAngle)  ->
    currentAngle = currentAngle # = 1

    switch @type
        # set @endAngle to pick up later on
        # Math.PI * 2 is the endpoint of a circle divided by seconds times current seconds
        when "seconds" then @endAngle = Math.PI * 2 / 60 * @seconds
        when "minutes" then @endAngle = Math.PI * 2 / 60 * @minutes
        when "hours" then @endAngle = Math.PI * 2 / 24 * @hours


    @context.arc(@center_x, @center_y, 100, @startAngle, currentAngle, @counterClockWise)
    @context.lineWidth = 15

    console.log('drawn')

    text = "28px sans-serif";
    @context.fillText(text, @center_x - 28, @center_y - @canvas.width / 5)

    @context.stroke()


    currentAngle++;
    if currentAngle < @endAngle
        requestAnimationFrame( -> @drawFirstLine(currentAngle / 100) )
```

As you can see at the bottom of the above code I am trying to call the function where we are in, again and again. But the problem is that I can't use `@drawFirstLine` inside another function(the requestAnimationFrame function). In plain javascript I can use `var self = this` and refer to self. But does anyone  know how to deal with this in coffeescript?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble referencing class object inside a nested function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281886/trouble-referencing-class-object-inside-a-nested-function)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Use the fat arrow.](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow)

```
requestAnimationFrame( => @drawFirstLine(currentAngle / 100) )
```

which compiles to:

```
var _this = this;

requestAnimationFrame(function() {
  return _this.drawFirstLine(currentAngle / 100);
});
```

It basically does the `self = this` for you, making `this` or `@` inside the function what `this` is when that function is declared.  It's very handy, and it's probably my favorite feature of coffeescript.

Comment: But won't you still run into trouble when using the fat arrow if you're several callbacks deep? Or will it always refer to the outermost this?

Comment: @RyanWilcox If you continue to use `=>` as you nest functions, `this` will be maintained. [The proof is here!](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%40foo%20%3D%20'bar'%0A%0Acallback%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20anothercallback%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20hollaback%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20alert%20%40foo)

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time in my app at work.

```
drawFirstLine: (currentAngle)  ->
    currentAngle = currentAngle # = 1
    self = @

    ....
```

Remember, in Coffeescript you don't need `var`: this will stay local to the context of the `drawFirstLine` function. (it'll generate `var self = this`).